# Viewing and Updating Related Record when creating a Task

Tags: field-update, required-field, relatedrecord

I might have been overly optimistic about coming up with a solution for the users.
When a user creates a Task from an Account meeting certain criteria (Account Type = XX), they want to require some Account fields if they are null.
As opposed to a validation rule, which would require them to cancel the activity, go back to the Account and populate the fields, then create the Task again, they want the users to be able to enter the Account data at the same time.
I thought I could just add a Related Record component with an Account Update Action to the Task Page and make the specific fields required.
This isn't working as I thought- while the Related Record section on the Task page is visible on existing records, it's not available when CREATING the new Task record which is when its needed.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible and I'm just doing something wrong? If this is not a viable solution does anyone know of one without using custom code or Lwc (no developer available)?
NOTE: The Account object was renamed "Company"

Answer (score 2):

You can create a screenflow and attach it as a QuickAction in your Account (Company) object.

The advantages of these are:

1. You can get the Account record and check the Account Type, based on different Account Type you can traverse different paths and show different screens.

For an example:

1. User wants to create a new Task from Account(Company). They click on the QuickAction (screenflow). (Using decision element) If the Account Type = XX and some of the fields are empty, you can show different screens and on each different screens you can set different required fields.

Additional tips:

- When you are creating a screenflow, create a new variable of type
  record and name it "recordId" (excluding the ""). Make sure you
  select type **Record**. By doing so, you do not have to use a get
  element to fetch the current Account to check which fields are blank,
  instead the recordId variable will capture all the information of the
  account.

and of course, you would want to prevent the user's from creating a new task from the related list by following @fred answer.

Comment: Thanks @prem22 for the suggestion. I'm still having a hard time creating the Flow and determining which elements to use when, and how to set visibility conditions on the related Account fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in on the Lightning page.

- Hide the default New Task button
- Create a new button that directs to the New Task page
- Use conditional visibility to only show that button when the correct criteria are met. And a warning message if they are not.

Comment: When you say to create a new button that directs to the New Task page, could you elaborate? I didnt create a new Task Page Layout, I just updated the Task Lightning page to have the Related Record component

Comment: My idea would be that users would create the Task from the Company page. You can't conditionally hide the new Task button when it's on the related list but you can if it's a button on the page (in the top right).

Comment: I'm still not sure how to create a button on the Account/Company object that will create a Task using standard config. The only choices are 2 custom code ones (VF & Javascript) or a URL and I'm not sure how the URL function works.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to bring Account fields inside Task record creation layout.

You can prefer one of the below options as solution.

1. For Open Activity section, you can set the Visibility criteria and show it only when the required fields of Accounts are populated.
2. Create a custom New Task button and initiate a screen flow to do the creation.

Comment: I am able to bring the Account fields into the Task Page using the related record component on the Task Lightning page with a custom action named Update Account details My problem is getting that Task Page to be available during the CREATION of a Task. It's only available when VIEWING existing Tasks currently. Is there no way to surface the Task page layout when creating a new Task?